# Employee performance entry and review by Manager with comments

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to build `Employee performance entry` and `review functionality` in SharePoint and I am a new bee in SharePoint. I am confused on picking up the right approach here.

Please suggest me the best approach here?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please add more details to narrow in on what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thanks Robert for your reply. I am trying to automate employee performance review through share point. Here Employee will answer a set of questions those evaluates the performance during a period(yearly). Once Employee submits the review, Manager will review the employee answers abd share his feedback on that.